# Can every operator on a finite-dimensional vector space be diagonalised?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

[image]

This is a page from the book 'Linear algebra done right'. The assumption that V is finite-dimensional is not stated. This proof seems to imply that every operator on a finite-dimensional vector space can be diagonalised. Is that true? I recall being told that diagonalising linear maps is not easy, so I wonder if I am misinterpreting this.

Comment: I think it only says that operators of the special form $\sqrt{T^*T}$ can always be diagonalized.

Comment: Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$, where $F$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. The singular value decomposition theorem tells us that if $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then there exist orthonormal ordered bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $V$ and $W$, respectively, such that the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is diagonal. It is remarkable that *any* linear transformation from $V$ to $W$ can be represented by a diagonal matrix. But notice that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different bases, even if $V = W$.

Comment: So does this mean that every operator is diagonalisable as long as alpha and beta are not required to be the same?

Comment: It depends on the precise definition of "diagonalizable". I think the precise definition is that a linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an ordered basis $\beta$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $\beta$ is diagonal. Equivalently, $T$ is "diagonalizable" if and only if there exists a basis of eigenvectors for $T$. So, that means that if you need two different bases to get the matrix of $T$ to be diagonal, then $T$ is not "diagonalizable". But I need to double check the precise definition of "diagonalizable".

Comment: The assumption that V is a *finite-dimensional* vector space is stated on the opening page of Chapter 7.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the assumption was not explicitly stated in the proof. I'm really enjoying your book by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, general linear transformations can be written in *Jordan normal form* which is the best thing we can say about diagonalization in general.

However, for any *self adjoint* transformation $U$ ($U^*=U$) there's an orthonormal basis where its matrix is diagonal. (That's basically the Spectral theorem.)
In particular, this holds for the positive semidefinite $\sqrt{T^*T}$.